# Integration of $e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus

I have this problem I am working on:
$$\int_{} {} e^{-x}dx, u= -x$$

This is what I have so far:
$$\int_{} {}e^{u}(-du)$$

But the answer is

$$-e^{-x} + C$$

Shouldn't $$e^u$$ become $$e^{u^2/2}$$

Comment: no It shouldn't. And the answer is $-e^{-x}+C$ you forgot the sign. Note that $\frac{d}{dx} (e^{\frac{x^2}{2}})=xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Comment: Is it because the u in question is an exponent and for exponents you don't change them?

Comment: Yeah pretty much that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, why should it? The integral which by substitution is equivalent to the first is
$$
-\int e^{u}\mathrm du=-e^{u}+C
$$
Now what is $u$? It's $-x$, so substitute back in for the variable you actually care about to find antiderivative
$$
-e^{-x}+C
$$
Don't believe me? Differentiate and use the FTC to verify that 
$$
(-e^{-x}+C)'=e^{-x}
$$
as we expected.

Comment: For a second opinion. Do we not integrate exponents? Since u is an exponent does it not become $$u^2/2$$

Comment: $\int e^xdx=e^x$ but $\int u^ndu=\frac {u^{n+}}{n+1}$

Comment: @Jinzu no, what happens if you differentiate what you think is the antiderivative

Comment: @qbert: I get the same answer: 
It becomes $$2u/2$$

Comment: what exactly are you differentiating?

Comment: this: $$-e^{u^{2}/2} + C$$

Comment: then you are doing so incorrectly. Please review the chain rule and see the comment on your original post